# store a string to integer array

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to read a number ( 12 digit ) as a string and then copy it into an integer array but not getting it right.

My code is here :

```
//header files
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

// namespace 
using namespace std ;

int main ()

{
    string input ;

    do
    {
        cout << "Make sure the number of digits are exactly 12 : ";
        cin >> input ;
    } while((input.length()) != 12 );

    int code[11] ; // array to store the code


    //change string to integer
    int intVal = atoi(input.c_str());


    //
    for (int i = 12; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        code[i] = intVal % 10;
        intVal /= 10 ;
        cout << code[i] ;
    }


    cout << endl ;
    //now display code
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 11 ; i++)
    {
        cout << code[i];
    }

    system ("pause") ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

So , for a basic input of 123456789101. it should be stored in the code[] array.

So when I am displaying the code loop I want to make sure it's same as 123456789101.

but it's coming to this :

during the code

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 11 ; i++)
{
cout << code[i];
}
```

it shows 00021474836 , where I want it to display me the number back !

Comment: Please be more precise than "not getting it right". What, exactly, is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To turn string to int array, try:

```
std::string input = "123456789101";
int code[12];

for (int i = 0 ; i < 12 ; i++)
{
  code[i] = input.at(i) - '0';
}
```

Also intvVal is not big enough to hold `123456789101`

Comment: thanks that seemed to work. However when I am displaying using a loop where i < 11 , it shows only until 12345678910. Why isn't it showing the full digit ?

Comment: `input = "123456789101";` has 12 digits, you only loop 11 digits

Comment: for some wierd reason , i ran it on shell and it was showing the correct result. So, I would guess, my visual studio is all messed up. Thanx !!

Answer (score 2):

`code` has a length of 11, but you're trying to access indices 12 and 11 in your `for` loop, neither of which exist. Second of all, a 12-digit number will not fit in a regular 32-bit integer, the maximum value is either 2147483647 for a signed 32 bit integer.

Try using [`atol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atol/) and storing the value in a `uint64_t`, and fix your array indices (The length should be 12, and the indices should be 0-11).